# QPointer and deleting objects

Tags: qt, qdialog, qpointer

I've got a Qt App that uses `QPointers` to bring up new UI Dialogs (Widgets). The main app can have numerous of the same widget loaded with different data. The problem I'm having is in deleting and freeing the memory for each widget. If I monitor the RAM usage of the program, each time I click the button to open one of these new widgets, it increases the ram and when I close the widget, it doesn't seem to be freeing the ram. I've tried using `deleteLater` and other solutions but keep getting crashes in the program.

Some example code is here:

```
QPointer<ListReservations> listResWindow = new ListReservations(resID);
listResWindow->setNum(numpeople);
listResWindow->show();
```

This will call the "`ListReservations`" widget which is declared as a `QDialog` (NOT modal). In that dialog I then have a button to close the window that calls the `QWidget::close()` slot.

I guess the question is how does my main program (that has the `QPointer`) know when the dialog is closed and then free the dialog and (if possible) delete the pointer to save even more memory...

I thought you might be able to do a `QConnect()` to the `QPointer` object, but I can't seem to find any signals or slots that would allow the passing of the pointer, much less send the signal once the dialog is indeed closed and ready for deletion.

Maybe I need some sort of function in the main program that takes a generic pointer object and then have the `QDialog` call that before calling it's own close slot? In that function it would pass itself to be destroyed? Just throwing out ideas that I've tried to implement but failed at....

I don't think I can reuse the same pointer elsewhere because in theory you could have multiple `ListReservations` windows open at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you set the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute flag on your dialog using `QWidget::setAttribute()`. That should make sure that the dialog is properly destroyed when it is closed. See the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) for more details.

Assuming that memory is now properly freed, the pointer should invalidate itself, from the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qpointer.html):

> A guarded pointer, QPointer,
>   behaves like a normal C++ pointer T *,
>   except that it is automatically set to
>   0 when the referenced object is
>   destroyed (unlike normal C++ pointers,
>   which become "dangling pointers" in
>   such cases)

Comment: Your first advice for delete on close is spot-on.  However, the QPointer objects will be set to NULL automatically when the object it points to is deleted, so there shouldn't be a need for the onDialogClosed slot (that I can see).

Comment: I have never used `QPointer` before and assumed it did not have that behavior, thanks for the info. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I should also add that there are potential race conditions in using a QPointer to an object that is owned by a different thread.  In that case, it would be possible for the object to be deleted without the QPointer object being set to 0 yet.